# How to backup relevant files?

Tags: android, sqlite, version-control, backup

My app is getting to the point where I will be highly perturbed if I lose the source somehow. This is a personal / single developer project, so something like Subversion might be overkill. I'm thinking more along the lines of the "Backup" agent that is a part of the GExperts add-on in the Delphi world. Is there such a thing (that would backup all the .java, .xml, sqlite, etc. files) specifically for or suitable for the Android platform?

Comment: I never ever do something without Git/Subversion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion using a version controll system is not overkill at all. You can keep hand on changes all the time. Making features that you don't even know whether to include or not into main branch. Not only features but every complicated task also, for example refactoring. With VCS that's no problem to make fast fix to released product during development of a huge task which is incomplete.
I can't imagine working without any VCS. I prefer Git because is fast and easy.